# "is" operator in C# returns inconsistent results

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to use "is" operator in C# to check the runtime type of an object instance. But it doesn't seem to work as I'd expect.

Let's say we have three assemblies A1, A2 and A3 all containing just one class.

A1:

```
public class C1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        C2 c2 = new C2();

        bool res1 = (c2.c3) is C3;
        bool res2 = ((object)c2.c3) is C3;
    }
}
```

A2:

```
public class C2
{
    public C3 c3 = new C3();
}
```

A3:

```
public class C3
{
}
```

A1 needs to reference A2 and A3.

A2 needs to reference A3.

After running Main() res1 and res2 are set to true as expected. The problem occurs when I start versioning A3 as strongly named assembly and make A1 to reference one version
and A2 to reference another version of A3 (the source code of A3 remains the same). Btw. compiler allows this only if the version of A3 referenced by A2 is lower or equal than
the version of A3 referenced by A1. The outcome of this program is now different (res1 = true, res2 = false).

Is this behaviour correct? Shouldn't they be both false (or perhaps true)?

According to C# 5.0 specification (chapter 7.10.10) both res1 and res2 should end up with the same value. The "is" operator should always consider run-time type of the instance.

In IL code I can see for res1 the compiler made the decission that both C3 classes coming from different A3 assemblies are equal
and emitted the code without isinst instruction checking against null only. For res2 compiler has added isinst instruction which postpones the decision for run-time.
It looks like C# compiler has different rule on how to resolve this than CLR run-time.

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       36 (0x24)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [A2]C2 c2,
           [1] bool res1,
           [2] bool res2)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void [A2]C2::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldfld      class [A3]C3 [A2]C2::c3
  IL_000d:  ldnull
  IL_000e:  ceq
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0011:  ceq
  IL_0013:  stloc.1
  IL_0014:  ldloc.0
  IL_0015:  ldfld      class [A3]C3 [A2]C2::c3
  IL_001a:  isinst     [A3_3]C3
  IL_001f:  ldnull
  IL_0020:  cgt.un
  IL_0022:  stloc.2
  IL_0023:  ret
} // end of method C1::Main
```

Could it be just trade-off for a faster and optimised implementation without using isinst (considering the compiler warning)?

Possible option to get around this is binding redirect (as suggested by the warning) but I can't use that as the versions may not always be backwards compatible (although C3 class always is). Changing the reference in A2 is also not an option for me.

EDIT: As it seems the easiest workaround is to always cast to object to get the correct result.

Anyway it would still be interesting to know if it's a bug in C# compiler (and possibly report it to MS) or not a bug per se (as compiler identifies a problem and reports a warning) although it could still generate a correct IL code.

Comment: The types *are* different as they come from *different* assemblies. An assembly's strong name includes the version number -  you explicitly specified that the two binaries are no longer the same, you don't consider them the same but the later one is compatible with the earlier one, provided no public types break compatibility. The C# rules deal with the language while you have two different IL binaries.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would expect to be different assemblies. So why is res1 set to true then?

Comment: What is the compiler warning?

Comment: A1 should reference both versions of A3.

Comment: Compiler warning: "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190"

Comment: A1 cannot reference both versions of A3. C3 class would become ambiguous. The namespace and the name are identical in both A3 assemblies. You would get compilation error "The type 'C3' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\A3\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b3f6cc5bfba5b5c0\A3.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\A3\v4.0_1.0.1.0__b3f6cc5bfba5b5c0\A3.dll'"

Comment: But this compilation error has known resolution: [`extern alias`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx).

Comment: That's true. But as it seems the easier workaround would be to always cast to object to get the correct result. With extern alias I'd need to specify additional command line options with correct assembly versions and then maintain them whenever they change. Anyway it'd still be interesting to know if it's a bug (and possibly report it to MS) or not a bug per se (as compiler identifies a problem and reports a warning) although it could still generate a correct IL code.

Comment: If you build from project (and looks like you do so) you can specify alias in reference properties, so you does not need to bother with command line directly.

Comment: And I does not think that this is a bug. You can actually write `C3 c3=c2.c3;`, but `c3` and `c2.c3` actually have different types, and this will compile. And if you does not provide right binding redirects at runtime, then this code will be considered as unverifiable. So when you provide only one reference to A3 compiler thinks that you actually want to unify both assembles into one and handle C3 as single type regardless of different assembles.

Comment: To specify alias in reference properties is good point. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly I want compiler to handle C3 as a single type regardless of different assemblies. Otherwise I would specify the second reference and provide namespace prefixes. Every occurence of C3 in the source is without a namespace prefix so we can't expect that on one line "C3" identifier would be treated differently than the same "C3" identifier on the other line. It's correct that compiler treats them equally as coming from the only reference specified in A1.

Comment: So the same question comes again. Why then is res1 set to true and res2 set to false? Shouldn't they be both false if compiler works correctly(with regard to spec) and treats all "C3" identifiers equally as coming from A3 with higher version?
All I'm saying is that compiler doesn't know at compilation time what is the correct result of "is" operator so it should emit isinst instruction for res1 too.It's too early for compiler to decide.What if I add binding redirect manually after compilation.Both results should be then true. But if I don't add it both results should be set to false.

Comment: Compiler doesn't complain about missing reference. It complains about conflict between different versions of the same assembly. Which means it knows about both references and even if not it can figure it out from A2 reference. I know the ideal solution is to add the binding redirect. But I'm still interested how should this edge case without the redirect be resolved.
Btw. shouldn't I get verification exception in case it's unverifiable?

Comment: You will get `VerificationException`, when you in context what does not allow unverifiable code, for example: security transparent code. And if context allows unverifiable code, you in a vary big trouble: even change in order of fields or virtual methods in `C3` can break anything. Do you really need correctly working `is` in that case? Should C# compiler drop optimization of `is` to work correctly in cases where there is no guarantees to work? P.S. comments are really not suited for that kind of discussion.

Comment: I thought Microsoft's C# compiler produces safe and verifiable code by default (unless using unsafe which I'm not). PEVerify tool also reports "Verified". I've also tried to run it in different security context and got the same wrong results without VerificationException.

Comment: Code will be verifiable if you provide binding redirects, as compiler assumes by warning CS1701. And if all you do is an `is` check, then code will be verifiable, but If you call any method on `C3` instance, that came from different assembly, it will not.

Comment: That's true. Good point. Strange that Visual Studio doesn't warn you about the assembly not being verifiable any more.
Jeffrey Richter in his book "CLR via C#" stated that "By default, Microsoft's C# compiler produces safe code. Safe code is code that is verifiably safe". "By default" from the context of the book means "if not using unsafe". So this would need to be corrected to as far as there are no warnings.

Comment: Btw. this potential bug produces another wrong behaviour. If I add a new method Print() to the higher version of A3 this statement would work although I think it shouldn't.
c2.c3.Print();
There is no exception at all. Just that the code is not verifiable any more which is something not very obvious from Visual Studio IDE.
I would expect to get at least InvalidCastException or MissingMethodException if not a compilation error.

Comment: I can not find relevant piece of documentation, but I think that your scenario (provide only single reference to A3 and not provide binding redirects at runtime) just not designed to work. So, it actually have much more problems then incorrect result of `is` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't have an answer to why the first result yields true. However, if the spec says that `is` is supposed to be based on the runtime type, Panagiotis is correct; the types are different and both should return false. GetType() and typeof behave as `is` should.

```
var res3 = c2.c3.GetType() == typeof(C3);              // is false
var res4 = ((object)c2.c3).GetType() == typeof(C3);    // is false

var localC3 = new C3();
var res5 = localC3 is C3;                              // is true
var res6 = ((object)localC3).GetType() == typeof(C3);  // is true
```

My knee-jerk reation would be get rid of the object cast as that seems to work as you want.

However, as that may change if `is` is fixed. You could resort to the following. Since your code was compiled against signed assemblies, people won't be able to substitute a fake assembly.

```
var res7 = c3.GetType().FullName == typeof(C3).FullName
```

Hopefully, some of this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `res1`'s equation is compiled to `true` by the C# compiler (as shown by the IL). However `res2` is performing the correct analysis as it is doing it at run-time (any time you cast to `object` it forces C# to fall back to run-time operations for most things).

So it appears that the compiler assumes the types are the same (likely not validating the version of the constituent DLL).

The only solution that comes to mind easily is to change the alias of one of them and see if qualifying which C3 you are talking about helps.